# SSR with express/reactjs/nextjs - best approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

I want to write application which is SSR. The first thought was to use Next.js, but I see that it is not so good when API is complex. I need something like express + view engine (i.e. ejs) but with React.js so and I'm thinking about two options:

1. Use Express + ReactDOMServer and serve html files that way
2. Use Express + Next.js within the same repository, and any API call will be not served from Next /pages/api, but from express REST API

Do you have any experience with that problem? Or maybe is another better option for this?
Thanks in advance